# Http Redirect 302

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, redirect, http-status-code-302

I m trying to make a HTTP 302 Redirect, but getting the following exception while I'm running in debug mode.

```
Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack
```

---

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response; 
response.Clear(); 
response.Status = "302 Found";
response.AddHeader("Location", "http://google.com"); 
response.End();
response.Flush();
```

Long story short, this call is not flushing the response and not redirecting.

How can I get this working?

Comment: Did you compile your app in debug mode and running like so or you compiled your app in release mode and simply attaching the debugger to the process?

Comment: Take a look here as well http://automagical.rationalmind.net/2010/03/08/response-redirect-and-302-and-301-status-codes/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling both `End` and `Flush` in this way - for redirecting with HTTP 302 you should use `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect` see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx

Comment: is that 302 redirect? that worked for me, but i m not sure if that s 302

Answer (score 6):

The `HttpResponse` object has a method for performing a 302 redirect.

```
Response.Redirect("page.aspx")
```

Although your code should work fine as that is a common way to implement a `301 redirect`.

Note that `response.Flush()` is redundant as the response buffer is flushed to the client and execution will end on `response.End()`, so that line will not be executed.

A google search for others with [similar problems](http://forums.asp.net/t/984756.aspx) points to this KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/ which is likely to be the cause of your problems.

Comment: is that 302 redirect? that worked for me, but i m not sure if that s 302

Comment: Yes it is according to the documentation, you can use something like firebug or fiddler to check.